# How to print out strings with unicode escape characters correctly

Tags: python, string, translation

I am reading strings from a file which contain embedded unicode escape sequences,
`\u00e9` as an example.
When I print the literal strings using `print()`, the encodings are translated by print into the correct character but if I get the strings from stdin and print them out, print doesn't convert the escape sequences into the unicode characters.

For example, when I use:

```
print ("Le Condamn\u00e9 \u00e0 mort")
```

python correctly prints `Le Condamné à mort`
however, if I get the same string from stdin I get: `Le Condamn\u00e9 \u00e0 mort`

Does anyone know how I can get python to translate the escape sequences to the correct unicode characters? Also, why does `print` behave differently when you give it a string literal rather than a string variable?

Comment: Why does your file contain literal escape sequences instead of the actual characters corresponding to those escape sequences?

Comment: I don't know. Its a json data dump that is coming from an external source.

Comment: "Its a json data dump" - then use a JSON decoder! Don't try to parse it manually.

Comment: For your second question, it sounds like you're confusing data and representation. The backslashes in a string literal are not actually literal, they're escape sequences. So if your file contains `\u00e9`, the string that represents it is `'\\u00e9'`. Note the double backslash. Meanwhile if your source code contains the string `'\u00e9'`, when you print it, it turns into `é`. Anyway, `print()` has nothing to do with it; it's just how strings work.

Comment: OK. I've replaced those escape sequences with a double backslash, print still doesn't interprets them it just prints them with a double backslash.

Comment: @user2418063 Why are you adding another backslash?

Comment: based on the comment before "So if your file contains \u00e9, the string that represents it is '\\u00e9'."  So I tried to make my input match the expected escape sequence so it will be interpreted correctly but no dice.

Comment: @user2418063 I'm saying the exact opposite of that, but also, I'm not talking about a solution, just the concepts behind this problem. For a solution, did you try using a JSON decoder like user2357112 suggested?

Comment: My issue is not in parsing out the json data its in printing out the correct representation of a string in python.  The strings are already extracted from the json source correctly and are in a separate text file. The json file itself contains those same exact encodings in the field values. My issue is how to go about translating these embedded escape sequences back into the appropriate unicode characters using Python.

Comment: @user2418063 Then it sounds like the JSON is malformed. Could you post a sample so we can take a look?

Comment: I just checked and JSON seems to use something like UTF-16 for its escape sequences, which Python doesn't support out of the box. For example, the grinning face emoji: `print(json.dumps('\U0001F600'))` -> `"\ud83d\ude00"`

Comment: "The strings are already extracted from the json source correctly" - no they're not. Extracting them correctly would involve using a JSON parser, which would perform JSON escape sequence handling as part of its job. You just pulled raw substrings out of the JSON text, which is *not* how you correctly extract data from JSON.

Comment: Note that JSON escape sequence handling is **not the same** as Python string literal escape sequence handling. JSON defines its own escape sequence rules, which closely resemble Python's escape sequence rules, but have several differences.

Comment: You can simply encode and decode your string like this: `print(string.encode().decode('unicode-escape'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\u00e0` is being stored as a Unicode number for python so that it is printed as a 'à'. When you get it from another file, it is completely in string form meaning it is then stored as a `'\\u00e0'` where every character is a string.
A solution to this would be to identify where the `'\\u00e0'` is in the list and then replace it with the `'\u00e0'`

Here is some code that will convert the `'\\u00e0'` in the string into the character its supposed to be.

```
def special_char_fix(string):
    string = list(string)
    for pl, char in enumerate(string):
        if char == '\\':
            val = ''.join([string[pl + k + 2] for k in range(4)])
            for k in range(5):
                string.pop(pl)
            string[pl] = str(chr(int(val, 16)))
    return ''.join(string)
```

Comment: This code works well, thanks! Picking this answer as it actually addresses the issue at hand  and does it in a very creative way! Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you! I've recently made this account just to answer python questions. its nice to hear you like the solution.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that you are looking for  str.encode("string-escape") function

example code

```
s = "Le Condamn\u00e9 \u00e0 mor"
ra=s.encode('unicode_escape').decode()
print(ra)
```

output

```
Le Condamn\xe9 \xe0 mor
```

[the image contains the code snippet with output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FooW3.png)

Comment: i have tried to convert the string to raw string hope it helps

Comment: Dear @Eijun, actually question is not about converting string to raw string. But quite the opposite. So fix your answer to this -> print(open('filename').read().encode().decode('unicode-escape'))

Comment: These solutions don't appear to be working.